# jQuery/AJAX load event on individual HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please I have multiple HTML pages with each having a separate .js file. I want to recognize each page by URL and load each implementation on page load. I understand I can check load event on HTML element using jQuery like

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

As specified here. How do I extend that to the pages? I want to execute a jQuery/AJAX load event on each of my HTML pages to check few things like user status or authorization. Example to check if user is logged in, then proceed and execute other jQuery codes, otherwise redirect user to login page.

Comment: Check the user is logged in with server side code before giving them the page they have to be logged in to see (rather than giving them the page they have to be logged in to see and then attempting to redirect if they are not).

Comment: "I understand I can check load event on HTML element using jQuery like" — You can't. That will make an Ajax request for `ajax/test.html` and drop the content into the element. To test for a load event use `$(document).on('load', someFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

In page header do a authentication check and redirect user to login page.

```
$(function() {
    $('#result').load('auth/test', function( response, status, xhr ) {
        if (response == 'guest') {
            window.location = 'auth/login';
    }
});
```

You can either put this code in separate file and include the file in every page or use some template hierarchy to achieve this.